# error 001: expected token: "=", but found "["

Tags: pawn

got this error on this line:

```
const int restricted_weapons[] = { WEAPON_AK47, WEAPON_AWP, WEAPON_M4A4 };"
```

By the way this is SourcePawn
i thought about something but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `const`.

If the dimension of the array is known at compile time (seems to be the case in your example), add the dimension in between the brackets.

`int restricted_weapons[3] = { WEAPON_AK47, WEAPON_AWP, WEAPON_M4A4 };`

if the dimension is not known, use the new keyword:

`int[] array = new int[size];`